# How to use composite handler with nested open generic?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, open-generics

```
public interface IMessage { }
public interface ICommand : IMessage { }
public interface IEvent : IMessage { }

public interface IMessageHandler<T> {
    void Handle(T message);
}

public class ItemCreatedEvent : IEvent {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ValidateMessageEnvelope<TMessage> {
    public TMessage Message { get; set; }
    public ValidateMessageEnvelope(TMessage message){
        Message = message;
    }
}

public class ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler<TMessage> 
    : IMessageHandler<ValidateMessageEnvelope<TMessage>> {
    private readonly IMessageHandler<TMessage> _innerHandler;
    public ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler(IMessageHandler<TMessage> innerHandler){
        _innerHandler = innerHandler;
    }
    public void Handle(ValidateMessageEnvelope<TMessage> message){
        _innerHandler.Handle(message.Message);
    }
}

public class SecureMessageEnvelope<TMessage> {
    public TMessage Message { get; set; }
    public string UserToken { get; set; }
    public SecureMessageEnvelope(TMessage message, string userToken){
        Message = message;
        UserToken = userToken;
    }
}

public class SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler<TMessage> 
    : IMessageHandler<SecureMessageEnvelope<TMessage>>
{
    private readonly IMessageHandler<TMessage> _innerHandler;
    public SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler(IMessageHandler<TMessage> innerHandler){
         _innerHandler = innerHandler;
    }
    public void Handle(SecureMessageEnvelope<TMessage> message){
         _innerHandler.Handle(message.Message);
    }
}

public class MessageLogDecorator<TMessage> : IMessageHandler<TMessage> 
    where TMessage : IEvent {
    private readonly IMessageHandler<TMessage> _messageHandler;
    public MessageLogDecorator(IMessageHandler<TMessage> messageHandler) {
        _messageHandler = messageHandler;
    }
    public void Handle(TMessage message){
        Console.WriteLine("Event Log: {0}",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
        _messageHandler.Handle(message);
    }
}

public class CompositeMessageHandler<TMessage> : IMessageHandler<TMessage> {
    private readonly IEnumerable<IMessageHandler<TMessage>> _handlers;
    public CompositeMessageHandler(IEnumerable<IMessageHandler<TMessage>> handlers){
        _handlers = handlers;
    }
    public void Handle(TMessage message) {
        foreach (var messageHandler in _handlers) {
            messageHandler.Handle(message);
        }
    }
}

public class LogService :IMessageHandler<ItemCreatedEvent> {
    public void Handle(ItemCreatedEvent message) {}
}

public class ProjectionService: IMessageHandler<ItemCreatedEvent> {
    public void Handle(ItemCreatedEvent message) { }
}

public static class Extensions{
    public static SecureMessageEnvelope<TMessage> AsSecure<TMessage>(
        this TMessage message, string userToken){
        return new SecureMessageEnvelope<TMessage>(message, userToken);
    }
    public static ValidateMessageEnvelope<TMessage> AsValidatable<TMessage>(
        this TMessage message){
        return new ValidateMessageEnvelope<TMessage>(message);
    }
}
```

Register:

```
Container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof (IMessageHandler<>),
    Container.RegisterAll,
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// handle all ValidateMessageEnvelope<TMessage> messages
Container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IMessageHandler<>),
    typeof(ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler<>)); 

// handle all SecureMessageEnvelope<TMessage> messages
Container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IMessageHandler<>),
    typeof(SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler<>));

// handle all IEvent messages
Container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IMessageHandler<>), 
    typeof(MessageLogDecorator<>));
```

Event Call

```
var ev = new ItemCreatedEvent().AsSecure("token/1").AsValidatable();
    var handlerType = typeof(IMessageHandler<>).MakeGenericType(ev.GetType());
    foreach (dynamic handler in _container.GetAllInstances(handlerType)){
        handler.Handle((dynamic)ev);    
    }
```

return empty but must return two handler:

```
handler[0] = 
    new ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler<SecureMessageEnvelope<ItemCreatedEvent>>(
        new SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler<ItemCreatedEvent>(
            new MessageLogDecorator<ItemCreatedEvent>(
                new LogService())));

handler[1] = 
    new ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler<SecureMessageEnvelope<ItemCreatedEvent>>(
        new SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler<ItemCreatedEvent>(
            new MessageLogDecorator<ItemCreatedEvent>(
                new ProjectionService())));
```

although it would be nice as follows:

```
new ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler<SecureMessageEnvelope<ItemCreatedEvent>>(
    new SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler<ItemCreatedEvent>(
        new CompositeHandler(
            new MessageLogDecorator<ItemCreatedEvent>(
                new LogService()),
            new MessageLogDecorator<ItemCreatedEvent>(
                new ProjectionService()))));
```

if I call   "_container.GetInstance(handlerType)" instead of "GetAllInstances" an error occured:

> There was an error in the registration of open generic type
>   IMessageHandler. Failed to build a registration for type
>   ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler>.
>   There was an error in the registration of open generic type
>   IMessageHandler. Failed to build a registration for type
>   SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler. The constructor of
>   the type SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler contains the
>   parameter of type IMessageHandler with name
>   'innerHandler' that is not registered. Please ensure
>   IMessageHandler is registered in the container, or
>   change the constructor of
>   SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler.

When I register CompositeHandler () I have error. ( Container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IMessageHandler<>), typeof(CompositeMessageHandler<>));)

> There was an error in the registration of open generic type
>   IMessageHandler. Failed to build a registration for type
>   ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler>.
>   Multiple observers of the ResolveUnregisteredType event are
>   registering a delegate for the same service type:
>   IMessageHandler>. Make sure
>   only one of the registered handlers calls the
>   ResolveUnregisteredType.Register method for a given service type.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration doesn't work because you are doing two things wrong:

1. You didn't register the `CompositeMessageHandler<T>`
2. You are calling `GetAllInstances` instead of `GetInstance`.

When you call `GetAllInstances` you only get a collection of handlers that are registered using the `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`, but in your example you are requesting an `IMessageHandler<ValidateMessageEnvelope<SecureMessageEnvelope<ItemCreatedEvent>>>`, but you never registered an `IMessageHandler<ValidateMessageEnvelope<T>>` as collection; the `ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler` is registered as 'single item' registration.

The regisration for the `CompositeMessageHandler<T>` is a bit more evolved, because you don't want the composite to be returned for all `IMessageHandler<T>` registrations. You don't want this, because if the message is a `ValidateMessageEnvelope<T>`, you want to return the `ValidateMessageEnvelopeHandler<T>` and if the message is a `SecureMessageEnvelope<T>`, you want to return the `SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler<T>`.

So you need to add the following registration AFTER the registrations for the `ValidateMessageEnvelope<T>` and  `SecureMessageEnvelopeHandler<T>`:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(
    typeof(IMessageHandler<>), 
    typeof(CompositeMessageHandler<>),
    Lifestyle.Singleton, 
    context => !context.Handled);
```

By supplying a `context => !context.Handled`, you make sure that the `CompositeMessageHandler<T>` only gets applied if no other registration was applied first. Without this predicate, Simple Injector will detect that two open-generic registrations are applied to the same abstraction and Simple Injector will throw an exception.

Instead of calling `GetAllInstances`, you should simply call `GetInstance`. For instance:

```
var ev = new ItemCreatedEvent().AsSecure("token/1").AsValidatable();
var handlerType = typeof(IMessageHandler<>).MakeGenericType(ev.GetType());

dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);

handler.Handle((dynamic)ev);
```

Do note though that your `MessageLogDecorator<T>` will not only get applied to the `LogService` and `ProjectionService` classes, but also to the `CompositeMessageHandler<T>` class. This might not be what you want. You might want to -only- wrap the `CompositeMessageHandler<T>`, or perhaps you want to wrap -everything but- the `CompositeMessageHandler<T>`. In the last case, you can change the `MessageLogDecorator<T>`'s registration to the following:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IMessageHandler<>),
    typeof(MessageLogDecorator<>), context =>
    {
        var type = context.ImplementationType;
        return !type.IsGenericType ||
            type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(CompositeMessageHandler<>));
    });
```

Or you might even be able to simplify it to the following:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IMessageHandler<>),
    typeof(MessageLogDecorator<>), 
    context => !context.ImplementationType.IsGenericType);
```

In which case the decorator will only get wrapped around non-generic implementations.

Comment: thanks for response,its works.BTW do I need CompositeMessageHandler<> ?

Comment: @oguzh4n: The composite pattern prevents application code to know about the fact that there are multiple implementations behind this. With your design using the envelope handlers, you clearly need this, since in your case sometimes you inject a single instance, while other times you inject the composite.  Both the envelope handlers and the ‘message executor mediator’ never know when this is the case (and they don’t need to know).